# What type of slider is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

Simple question, what type of slider is this: [http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/41373.html](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/41373.htm)

Are there any jQuery plugins that mimic the same effect.

Thank you

Comment: You can learn javascript, if you don't already know, and create your own :)

Comment: It's a template made in flash. There might be an analogue made with javascript but you have to tell us what do you refer to by saying "this slider".

Comment: I know it can be done in Javascript, that's what I planning to do using jQuery. I just wanted to see more examples online.
Of course it's made with flash on the site (no surprise)....

Comment: there are pre-made jquery sliders, if you don't want to re-invent the wheel you could always use them for whatever reason you like. except plagarism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a accordion horizontal slider. If you google it you'll find plenty. Here's some random result that looks like the one from your flash template: http://www.scriptocean.com/accordion.html

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "CSS menus" I found [this image menu with Jquery](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/examples/image-menu-2.html), and [here is the tutorial](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/create_image_menu_with_jquery.html).